# Xcode 7 - Can't Ad Hoc Sign My Project - Can't Select An account

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, adhoc, ad-hoc-distribution

I'm having trouble signing my Xcode app with Ad Hoc. I have a regular Apple Account, nothing fancy, and I used to be able to Ad Hoc but now for some reason I can't. When I go to sign it, it won't let me click the drop down icon, like their are no choices, or maybe my version of Xcode is broken. I'm really not sure. I took a bunch of screenshots which might help. And I did set all the variables in the plist file in Xcode, which I'm not sure is even necessary anymore.

**Everything I tried:**

**1)** Removing & Re-adding my account

**2)** Cleaning my project, and re-archiving

**3)** Setting my provisioning profile to "iOS Team Provisioning Profile: company.MyApp"

**4)** Setting my Team to "None"

**5)** Trying to sign it with my Keychain Developer Accounts

**6)** And other things that I can't remember currently

Also, I'm not sure its because I'm not in the Developer Program($99), but I can't connect to any of the developer tools on Apple's site. Everything just redirects me back to the Welcome page. So I can't do anything involving that.

Thanks, any help is appreciated

My Code Signing Build Setting:
[image: My Code Signing Build Settings]
My Accounts in Xcode:
[image: My Accounts in Xcode]
I can't click any accounts in the Export settings:
[image: I can't click any accounts in the Export settings]
My Signing Identities & Provisioning Profiles:
[image: My Signing Identities & Provisioning Profiles]

Comment: Are you using a free account ?

Comment: Yes, I haven't upgraded it or payed for anything. Just the normal account I use to buy stuff on my Mac and iPhone

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can see details of what you can do with diffrent kind of apple account in the table at bottom of below page in apple website:

[compare-memberships](https://developer.apple.com/support/compare-memberships/)

As you can see with free account (First column) you can not create ad-hoc builds.